# Could not find endpoint element

Tags: wcf, web-services, service-reference

The errror message is:

> Could not find endpoint element with name
>   'NetbiterServiceReference.nbws' and contract
>   'NetbiterServiceReference.nbws' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section.

My `app.config` file looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="nbws.cfcSoapBinding">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="nbws.cfcSoapBinding1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://../nbws.cfc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="nbws.cfcSoapBinding"
            contract="NetbiterServiceReference.nbws" name="nbws.cfc" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In my code I do like this and i gives the error message above.

```
 nbwsClient proxy = new nbwsClient();
```

Then I did all these combinations, but with the same result:

```
nbwsClient proxy = new nbwsClient("NetbiterServiceReference.nbws", "https://../nbws.cfc");
nbwsClient proxy = new nbwsClient("nbws", "https://../nbws.cfc");
nbwsClient proxy = new nbwsClient("nbws.cfc", "https://../nbws.cfc");
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself.
Problem was that the test-project, running the project with code and app.config didn’t have the correct information in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

The errror message is: Could not find endpoint element with name 'NetbiterServiceReference.nbws' and contract 'NetbiterServiceReference.nbws' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. My app.config file looks like this:

---

If you change the endpoint section as follows, you'll lose this error.

```
<endpoint address="https://../nbws.cfc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="nbws.cfcSoapBinding" 
            contract="NetbiterServiceReference.nbws" name="NetbiterServiceReference.nbws" />
```

Comment: Thank for the input, but it still does not work. Same error message.
Did a normal Webservice Reference and it works.
Would still like to get the Service Reference to work.